# Unity. Script does not working with clones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a script who will spawn objects and give  tag and color for one element of prefab. But script not working with clones. This 2 scripts, GameManager( he must spawn objects) and
RandomTagAndColor( he give to element of prefab tag and name). And in scene of game, where objects is spawning, script give tag and colour only to first prefab. In game those prefabs 10.  Well, I'm sorry if question is stupid, this first thing, what i doing without books,guides.

GameManager script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject firstBarrier;

    public GameObject secondBarrier;

    public int numOfBarriers = 0;

  

    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    System.Random rndY = new System.Random();

    Vector3 vector = new Vector3(5, 1/3 , 1);
    void Start()
    {
        for (numOfBarriers = 0; numOfBarriers < 10; numOfBarriers++)
        {
            int ewq = rnd.Next(1, 20);

            int rY = rndY.Next(1, 4);

            

            if(ewq <= 10)
            {
              Instantiate(firstBarrier, vector, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            else
            {
                Instantiate(secondBarrier, vector, Quaternion.identity);
            }

            vector.x -= 7;

            vector.y = rY;
        }
    }



    void Update()
    {
        
    }}
```

RandomColorAndTag script:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class RandomColorAndTag : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameObject Bar;
    
    System.Random randomElement = new System.Random();

    int el = 0 ;

  
    void Start()
    {
        el = randomElement.Next(2, 6);
       
            GameObject.Find($"Cube ({el})").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;

        if (GameObject.Find($"Cube ({el})").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == Color.green)
        {
            GameObject.Find($"Cube ({el})").transform.tag = "Green";
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {      
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't completely follow what you're trying to do. But, a question I have to ask is where is RandomColorAndTag script executed? Is it attached to one of the game objects being instantiated? And I would recommend you use UnityEngine.Random instead of System.Random as it's a static class, so you can access it from anywhere without having to create a new instance inside every class or object you need a random number.

Comment: yes, script RandomColorAndTag  attach to object. GameManager spawn this object, and this object it should spawn according to the script RandomColorAndTag.

Comment: GameManager spawning 10 object. Script RandomColorAndTag work at only 1 object spawned. But at others 9 object he doesn't work.

Comment: Totally confused by your code ... The `RandomColorAndTag` is it attached to the `GameMamager`? Or is it attached to the objects you are spawning? Why do they use `Find`? Why don't they just assign a random tag and color to **itself**? And you never change the name of the cloned thing at all so I doubt that `Find` will ever work at all .. what exactly do you mean by `doesn't work`? Getting any errors?

Comment: My object is a prefab. He  consists of 5 elements(Cubes). RandomAndColorTag must 
must assign a color and tag to one of the cubes(element of prefab). And this working, but only with the first created object. With the other 9 objects that the GameManager should create, this does not work. This is main problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there are lot of unclear issues in your codes.

- I will assume the `RandomColorAndTag` is attached to the objects you spawn. In that case don't use `Find` but rather simply assign the random color and tag to yourself
- what is a random value between 1 and 19 good for, of all you ever do with it is check whether it is bigger or smaller than 10? => Simply use only a random 0 or 1 and check whether it is 0 ;)
- I'm unsure exactly what items should be green now .. I assume among the 10 spawned items you want to pick one and make it special..
- finally I wouldn't even let the objects assign their own tag and color but let the `GameManager` trigger it

So I would do something like

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TagAndColorController fortBarrier;
    public TagAndColorController secondBarrier;
    public int numOfBarriers = 10;
    public Vector3 vector = new Vector3(5, 1f/3f , 1);

    public Color specialColor = Color.Green;
    public string specialTag = "Green";

    private void Start()
    {
        var specialIndex = Random.Range(0, numberOfBarriers);

        for (var i = 0; i < numOfBarriers; i++)
        {
            // upper bound is exclusive -> this returns 0 or 1
            var rndBarrier = Random.Range(0, 2);

            // not sure if intended but again: upper bound is exclusive -> this return 1, 2, or 3
            var rY = Random.Range(1, 4);

            var tagAndColor = Instantiate(rndBarrier == 0 ? firstBarrier : secondBarrier, vector, Quaternion.identity);

            if(i == numberOfBarriers)
            {
                tagAndColor.SetColorAndTag(specialColor, specialTag);
            }

            vector.x -= 7;
            vector.y = rY;
        }
    }
}
```

And the other script has no logic whatsoever but rather only is a quick access to the objects renderer and bundles the behavior

```
public class TagAndColorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;
  
    public void SetColorAndTag(Color newColor, string newTag)
    {
        gameObject.tag = newTag;
        if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        _renderer.material.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: My object is a prefab. He consists of 5 elements(Cubes). RandomAndColorTag must must assign a color and tag to one of the cubes. And this working, but only with the first created object. With the other 9 objects that the GameManager should create, this does not work. This is main problem. I chose random chiles up to 20, as I experimented(yes, I know that it doesn't affect anything, I just forgot to put 1 and 0 back). I repeat, the tag and color should be assigned to the prefab element, there are 5 elements in it (each of them is called a cube (number)). the game creates 10 such prefabs